# Print a list with names and ages and show their average age

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I am suposed to print a list with names and ages, each on a seperate row and then show their averagea age and I need some help.
This is what I got so far:

```
namn = ["Lena", 22, "Jonas", 26, "Anna", 27, "Kalle", 23, "Erik", 30, "Josefine", 20, "Emelie", 32, "Johanna", 29,
    "Peter", 19]
```

Comment: Show us the code you tried so far, and not only the declaration of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This also works:

```
pairs = dict([tuple(namn[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(namn), 2)])
for name, age in sorted(pairs.items()):
    print("%s: %d" % (name, age))

avg_age = sum(pairs.values())/ len(pairs)
print("Average Age: %f" % (avg_age))
```

Output:

```
Anna: 27
Emelie: 32
Erik: 30
Johanna: 29
Jonas: 26
Josefine: 20
Kalle: 23
Lena: 22
Peter: 19
Average Age: 25.333333
```

You could also extend this by sorting the names in alphabetical order too.

Comment: In Python 2 your code wouldn't calculate the average correctly. Indeed it would output ``Average Age: 25.000000`` because in Python 2 the operator ``/`` performs integer division.

Comment: Yeah I wrote this with python 3, the OP didn't specify.

Answer (score 0):

you must first create a dictionary.
Here`s the code

```
def name_age(namn):
    dic = {}
    age = 0
    for n in range(0, len(namn), 2):
        dic[namn[n]] = namn[n+1]
    for i in dic:
        print i, dic[i]
        age = age + dic[i]
    avg_age = age / len(dic)
    return avg_age
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
data = {name: age for name, age in zip(namn[0::2], namn[1::2])}
for name, age in data.iteritems():
    print '%11s: %d' % (name, age)
print 'Average age: %f' % (sum(data.values())/float(len(data)))
```